# Search for a keyword after some filter and return a value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

There is a filter applied to my range of data and i would like to search the keyword "abc" in column "I" after the filtering and return a value "Check" at the very end of my data column "W"

I have not know any example to this function but i do had a code before to search for value and delete the row if the amount is 0.

```
'Delete rows for zero value

 Dim LR As Long, i As Long

      With Sheets("tempp")

           LR = .Cells.Find(What:="0", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, 
           SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

           For i = LR To 1 Step -1
                If .Range("C" & i).Value = 0 Then .Rows(i).Delete
           Next i

      End With
```

Comment: Do you want to return "Check" only if you find "abc" in your column?

Comment: yes, i only need a check if there is "abc". would need to perform other check if it doesnt have abc

Comment: If a filter is applied you might want to look in `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: @ZhiYingChew please mark one of the below answers as correct so the thread can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will search your column I. Please adjust the sheet name to your need. It will return the checked status if "abc" is found. If it is not found you can run your desired check where stipulated.

```
Sub RangeCheck()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim lRowW as Long

'adjust the sheet name to your sheet name
Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find(What:="abc")

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
    'found abc, insert checked - presumably the last row of column W?
    lRowW = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("W" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("W" & lRowW).Value = "Checked"

    'if not last row in column W, then use the below
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("W1").Value = "Checked"
Else
    'if it does not find your string "abc" then insert the check you want to run here

End If

'clear object
Set myRange = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Dim c As Range

    'Going through each visible cell in *I* column. Change 5000 to the numbers of rows your sheet have

     For Each c In Worksheets("tempp").Range("I1:I5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'Checking if cell contains abc

        If InStr(c.Value, "abc") > 0 Then

            Worksheets("tempp").Range("W" & c.Row).Value = "Check"

        End If

    Next
```

Let us know if it works!